# Fancybox lib file (jquery.fancybox.css) shows as Render blocking script in google page insights test. solution?

Tags: html, performance, fancybox-3

Fancybox lib file (jquery.fancybox.css) shows as Render blocking script in google page insights test. solution????

I already trying lot but no success any help will be appreciated